# How do I make 3d molecular graphics similar to those shown on Wikipedia?

Tags: molecular-structure, cheminformatics

I want to make 3d molecular graphics similar to those found on Wikipedia. In the page for benzene, you can see the structure looks like this:
[image]

However, if I go to the interactive image as shown in here:

[image]

I get an interactive image that looks like this:
[image]

To me, the second image doesn't look nice, and I prefer the first one. However, I cant seem to find a way to get the image of first type for any molecule after converting from SMILES. I want to draw the structure of, say for example, Bismabenzene? How do I produce a graphical image for that if it's not available on Wikipedia?

Comment: [PyMol](https://www.pymol.org/) comes to mind. There are a ton of freebies out there. In the day (and still) there's [RasMol](http://www.openrasmol.org/).

Comment: @ToddMinehardt Any thats online? I'm not really up for downloading software for now.

Comment: Maybe [eMolecules](https://www.emolecules.com/)? Don't take my word for any of it, I'm old and not as informed as others on this site.

Comment: @ToddMinehardt C'mon, to me you seem to be quite up to date! Anyway,  just in case you need one: Here's a brotherly hug from a fellow chemist who has celebrated his 20th birthday more than once too ;-)

Comment: The person who made the benzene image (and many other molecules) has instructions for how they do it on their user page, if that helps: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/User:Benjah-bmm27/MakingMolecules

Comment: @KlausWarzecha - :)

Comment: A little odd representation like the second one may happen if the structure originally was drawn and saved as *.mol file with explicit hydrogen atoms.  If not switched off, Jmol will then compute the bonds automatically which however may be disabled (edit ->preferences -> bond).  Yet in favour of Jmol, the same index card has two rulers defining bond tolerance and minimal bond distance, which offers quite some advantage (compared to CCDC Mercury, for example) in the display of crystal structures with positionally disordered chains.

Comment: If you are by chance running a Linux based OS, there is a good chance your distro has Jmol in it's repos. It's large (~150M), but I had it downloaded, installed and running in about a minute. I like it. It takes common names, chemical names, SMILES, InChI and CAS, and of course create your own. And it is totally free (product and license) and guaranteed no adds or crapware included. This is the only *mol 3D type of product I've tried (I'm old too), so I can't say if it's better or worse than others.

Comment: @PrittBalagopal It looks like it's just a demographic survey on the linked Discovery Studio Visualizer download page, rather than a limitation on who can download. I'd recommend something like Industy:Other JobFunction:Research JobRole:Student CompanyName:<Your School name> -- or whatever you feel is "closest" to your actual situation. Try for the best match, but don't worry too much if it's not exact.

Comment: @R.M. Oh, that's nice, I'll try it.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Have a look at [Molcalc](http://molcalc.org/). It's fully online and uses JSmol as a visualiser.

Alternatively you can browse the [Pitt Quantum Repository](http://pqr.pitt.edu/) for structures that have already been calculated.

Comment: I want it to look like the one on Wikipedia

Comment: @Pritt If you want them to look like the ones on Wikipedia, I suggest you follow the link Carmeister has posted. You'll need to download and install programs though.

Answer (score 13):

You can generate the geometry for your molecule of choice by drawing it in [Avogadro](http://avogadro.cc/). More often than not, you want to refine the geometry through a force field calculation.

Avogadro supports multiple ways of visualization, which all can be configured according to your preferences. A ball-and-stick model, which you seem to prefer, is included.

If you want to generate an animation from the input file, [QuteMol](http://qutemol.sourceforge.net/) might be one option.

The interactive visualization on the wikipedia page of benzene is generated using **JSmol**, which is a JavaScript implementation of [Jmol](https://sourceforge.net/projects/jmol/).

If you are only interested in online tools, [MolView](http://molview.org/) could be an option.

Comment: Anything that's online? I'm not up for downloading software for now

Comment: Wow, MolView is a really cool toy. It's so much faster than Molcalc, unfortunately less accurate, but nevertheless a good starting structure generator.

Comment: @Martin-マーチン Honestly, I wasn't aware of the tool until 2 hrs ago :D Online searches are a blessing ;-)

Answer (score 1):

That Benzene molecular model you found on Wikipedia is uploaded by [Ben](https://commons.wikimedia.org/wiki/User:Benjah-bmm27), (a chemistry PhD student at the University of Bristol). He uses  [Avogadro](https://avogadro.cc/) and/or [CCDC Mercury](https://www.ccdc.cam.ac.uk/solutions/csd-core/components/mercury/). Both of them are free, cross-platform molecule editors which can be used to make 3-D Ball-and-stick models.

He previously used to have [Accelrys Discovery Studio](http://accelrys.com/products/discovery-studio/visualization/discovery-studio-visualizer.html) using which he made the original benzene molecule, but it is no longer supported.
[image]

See [this tutorial](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/User:Benjah-bmm27/MakingMolecules) on his user page about making molecules. Hope this helps. Have fun making molecules!

Comment: You have pretty much repeated the comment above from Carmeister. Please expand on this answer, otherwise it will be deleted and changed to a comment.